# onchange find this parent

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a few select boxes (at least 5) with the following structure

```
<li>
   <div>
      <select name="sb[]">...</select>
   </div>
</li>
```

When a sb change i want to make an ajax call pass the selected value and replace the content of parent li with the html receive from ajax.

I tried the following

```
onchange="
    $.get('file.php', { action: 'dothis'}, function(html) { 
      $(this).parent('li').html(html);
    });
"
```

but is not working

Any Help

Comment: `parent()` will only give you the *immediate* ancestor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('select[name="sb[]"]').change(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $.get('file.php', { action: 'dothis'}, function(html) { 
      $this.closest('li').html(html);
    });
})
```

Comment: +1, but you should either escape the [] of the name or wrap it in double quotes.. `[name=sb\\\[\\\]]` or `[name="sb[]"]`

Comment: It should also be a `.live()` or `.delegate()` binding since you overwrite the parent `LI Element`

Comment: @jAndy - yeah! nice point. But I don't know if the OP still want the `select` after the `ajax`... Well, that depends on the OP.. ;)

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that *change* will only work with *live* and *delegate* if you're using jQuery 1.4 or later

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want to, you could still do this in the onchange attribute. The problem is (as pointed out) twofold: firstly, the this inside the ajax callback is not the same this anymore as in the change event handler, secondly you should be using closest() or parents():

```
onchange="
    var select = $(this);
    $.get('file.php', { action: 'dothis'}, function(html) { 
      select.closest('li').html(html);
    });
"
```

or

```
onchange="
    $.get('file.php', { action: 'dothis'}, $.proxy(function(html) { 
      $(this).closest('li').html(html);
    }, this));
"
```